# Using abstract class as event Listeners?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a game and I'm using a lot of events to make one class communicate with others, but its tiresome to handle the subscription and the unsubscription on the OnEnable and OnDisable methods everytime that a new class will listen to a certain event. So I thought about making abstract classes for specific events and then, the class that wants to listen to the event will only have to inherit from the abstract class, to save time from setting up the method, OnEnable and OnDisable again.

The abstract class will be like this:

Lets say we have an event called OnGameStart. I'd make an abstract class just to listen to this event.

```
public abstact class OnGameStartListener : Monobehaviour
{
    private void OnEnable() => Controller.OnGameStart += OnGameStart;

    private void OnDisable() => Controller.OnGameStart -= OnGameStart;
    
    public abstract void OnGameStart();

}
```

Then, a class that wants to listen to this event would simply enherit from the abstract class and override the abstract method.

My question is: Is there a better way to do this? Or is this too much expensive? Because if a class Inherits from more than one abstract class to listen to events, we'd have more OnEnable and OnDisable methods being called.

Thanks for the time reading and answering ;)

I havent tried this yet, because Im not sure if its worth it. Not sure how I'd analyze the efficiency too.

Comment: use interface is better , because abstract have multiple implements problem

Comment: if use abstact you need be careful when you override `OnEnable()` and `OnDisable()`, it's not good to handle your script. I thought this design is too much expensive , I thoght just setting up the method for every new script is better.

Comment: Methods starting with `On*` have the conventional meaning of ***raising*** events, and not for attaching or handling events.

Comment: @Enigmativity to be fair Unity is also a bit inconsistent with that .. see `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` which get called by the Unity engine when according component gets enabled or disabled ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by TimChang in the comments: There is **no way** in c# that you

> Inherit from more than one abstract class

in the first place.

---

**If** you go for an `abstract class` you should make `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` rather `protected virtual void` and if you then `override` it in a child class make sure to also call `base.OnEnable();` accordingly. Otherwise there might be unexpected behavior as you don't know which of the `OnEnable` will be called by the engine.

Also `OnGameStart` should then rather be `protected abstract void` as there is no intend to have it called from the outside.

---

But if you say you have different events you should rather go for `interface`s.

Assume something like e.g.

```
public interface IGameStartListener
{
    void OnGameStart();
}

public interface IGameEndListener
{
    void OnGameEnd();
}
```

And then you can have a class like e.g.

```
public class Something : MonoBehaviour, IGameStartListener, IGameEndListener
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        Controller.AddListener(this);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        Controller.RemoveListener(this);
    }

    public void OnGameStart() { }

    public void OnGameEnd() { }
}
```

where your `Controller` can simply have multiple events and do something like e.g.

```
static event Action OnGameStart;
static event Action OnGameEnd;
...

public static void AddListener(object listener)
{
    if(listener is IGameStartListener gameStartListener)
    {
        OnGameStart += gameStartListener.OnGameStart;
    }

    if(listener is IGameEndListener gameEndListener)
    {
        OnGameEnd += gameStartListener.OnGameEnd;
    }

    ...
}

public static void RemoveListener(object listener)
{
    if(listener is IGameStartListener gameStartListener)
    {
        OnGameStart -= gameStartListener.OnGameStart;
    }

    if(listener is IGameEndListener gameEndListener)
    {
        OnGameEnd -= gameStartListener.OnGameEnd;
    }

    ...
}
```

For sure as you can see every implementer of the interfaces still has to ensure itself that it is properly registered and unregistered as a listener.

If you want to avoid this of course you still could simply have a base class that implements them all as [**`virtual`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) which means the behavior can be overwritten by any inheritor.

```
public abstract class MonoBehaviourGameEvents : MonoBehaviour, IGameStartListener, IGameEndListener, ...
{
    virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        Controller.AddListener(this);
    }

    virtual void OnDisable()
    {
        Controller.RemoveListener(this);
    }

    public virtual void OnGameStart() { }

    public virtual void OnGameEnd() { }

    ...
}
```

This would be more of a convinience implementation if you don't want to handle the registration yourself - but still using interfaces so you **can** be flexible if you want / need to

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface to implement the OnGameStart method, and create a helper component to help regist/unregist listener callback. With this kind of designing method, you can directly adjust the behaviour of event listener in inspector:

- StartListener interface:

  ```
    public interface IGameStartListener
    {
        // method needs to be implement
        public void OnGameStart();
    }
  ```
- Create a helper object like this:

  ```
    // helper object
    public class ListenerRegister : Monobehaviour
    {
        private IGameStartListener listener = null;

        private void Awake()
        {
            // attain corresponding component if exist.
            listener = GetComponent<IGameStartListener >();
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            if (listener) {
                Controller.OnGameStart += OnGameStart;
            }     
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            if (listener) {
                Controller.OnGameStart -= OnGameStart;
            } 
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: Methods starting with `On*` have the conventional meaning of ***raising*** events, and not for attaching or handling events.

Comment: that actually looks worst, we're adding and additional script (interface) and the other one   has the same purpouse of my abstract class

Comment: Your interface also has the same name as a class? o.O

Comment: @PedroHenriqueCherubini Sorry I miss type the interface name. But with this designing method, you can decide if you want to regist the listener behaviour through inspector. I If you don't want to use script to control, you can use a controller object to scan all objects that has IGameStartListener interface to regist with controller. I prefer this way because you can decouple the relationship between your listener object and controller.

Comment: I highlight the beahviour of the choice with attach/remove component through inspector, since through inherit, you can revert your modfication without changing your code. I suggest designing Unity project components with modularity in mind. However, this also depends on your project design. If you don't frequently change these settings, this approach may not necessarily be better.